# Php function call with dynamic name

Tags: php

I need to call functions as per foreach key value matches. Like asso1 key will call asso1() function and asso2 key will call asso2() function. I mean function name is dynamic. Array key value will be the functions name which need to be called. How can I achieve this?

```
function asso1() {
  echo "output form asso1";
}
function asso2() {
  echo "output form asso2";
}
function asso3() {
  echo "output form asso3";
}
$asso = array("asso1"=>"1", "asso2"=>"2", "asso3"=>"3");

foreach ($asso as $key => $_asso) {
  print_r($key);  //this will be name of function which need to be called.
  // print_r($_asso);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call_user_func is your savior. you can get more information from here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php

for example:

```
foreach ($asso as $key => $_asso) {
    call_user_func($key);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [call_user_func()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) function in this way:

```
foreach ($asso as $key => $_asso) {
    call_user_func($key);  
}
```

You can also use [Variable functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php)